# php imap, email sent from iphone with attached photo gives weird code

Tags: php, email, imap

Here the context before the question :
Context : I have a working web portal to send and receive emails.
I use imap_open with ressource, email pass, etc all that part is ok and working well for 99% of received emails

Question is the 1% not working
Example : someone have a iPhone and send an email to me with attached photo.

When I receive the email via my imap_open and imap_fetchbody and decoded according to imap encoding identified in the fetch_header... I get this

```
????EXIFMM* ???????? AppleiPhone........
```

why and how to fix it ?

here a sample of my code that handles the decoding

```
switch ( $imap_encoding ) {
                            case 0 :    $imapx__fetchbody = $imapx__fetchbody; break;
                            case 1 :    $imapx__fetchbody = quoted_printable_decode(imap_8bit($imapx__fetchbody)); break;
                            case 2 :    $imapx__fetchbody = imap_binary($imapx__fetchbody); break;
                            case 3 :    $imapx__fetchbody = imap_base64($imapx__fetchbody); break;
                            case 4 :    $imapx__fetchbody = quoted_printable_decode($imapx__fetchbody); break;
                            default :   $imapx__fetchbody = $imapx__fetchbody; break;
                        }

//test body if base64 because some emails have  miss identified imap_encoding
if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($imapx__fetchbody, true)) === $imapx__fetchbody){ $imapx__fetchbody = imap_base64($imapx__fetchbody); }
```

here a full body sample

[image]

Comment: can you post a sample email ?

Comment: @MaxMuster Hi, I tried to pasted it but because of weird code, stackoverflow says I cannot save, so I edited the question with a pic screen of what it looks like

Comment: please zip or rar or tar the file and put it somewhere where i can download it.

Comment: it looks like a picture in the exif format

Comment: @MaxMuster I found an other solution... When retrieving the imap_fetchbody I add a rule to check if the fetched body contains  ?exif, then pass to the other email part. *** your exif answer is nice too ;)

Answer (score 0):

you should read this :

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php

if shows you how to determine the image type. Specially for EXIF you must take this functions

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

and

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

You have two functions for decoding exif

```
Configuration options
----------------------
exif.encode_unicode             "ISO-8859-15"
exif.decode_unicode_motorola    "UCS-2BE"
exif.decode_unicode_intel       "UCS-2LE"
exif.encode_jis                 ""
exif.decode_jis_motorola        "JIS"
exif.decode_jis_intel           "JIS"
```

```php
Then you can write something like : 

<?php

    if (exif_imagetype('image.jpg') != IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

      echo 'The picture is a JPEG';

      ini_set('exif.decode_unicode_motorola', 'UCS-2LE');

      $data = exif_read_data('exifPicture.jpg');

      var_dump($data);

    }

?>
```